# HSQLDB & DBUnit, Cannot find column from ResultSetMetaData when using allias on SQL query

Tags: java, hsqldb, dbunit

I am using maven to build a project and got an error message:

```
o.d.database.DatabaseTableMetaData - Cannot find column from ResultSetMetaData             
info via DatabaseMetaData. Returning null.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did not find column 'T2_PRF_VALUE' for
<schema.table> 'PUBLIC.CDD_PRF_TABLE4' in catalog 'PUBLIC' because names do
not exactly match
```

I tried to dive into the DBUNIT and the HSQLDB Driver and didn't find any way to et over this warning.

my setup is (using maven):

> pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

hsqldb.script

```
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
ALTER USER SA SET INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
GRANT DBA TO SA
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_APP_TABLE1 (id INTEGER, value VARCHAR(20));
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_APP_TABLE2 (id INTEGER, value VARCHAR(20));
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_APP_TABLE3 (id INTEGER, value TIMESTAMP);
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_APP_TABLE4 (id INTEGER, value TIMESTAMP);
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_PRF_TABLE1 (id INTEGER, value VARCHAR(20));
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_PRF_TABLE2 (id INTEGER, value VARCHAR(20));
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_PRF_TABLE3 (id INTEGER, value TIMESTAMP);
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CDD_PRF_TABLE4 (id INTEGER, value TIMESTAMP);
```

> query.sql

```
SELECT T1.VALUE as T1_PRF_VALUE,
   T2.VALUE as T2_PRF_VALUE
FROM CDD_PRF_TABLE3 AS T1 inner join CDD_PRF_TABLE4 AS T2
ON T1.ID= T2.ID
```

> Main.java

```
final public static String  URL  =  "jdbc:hsqldb:res:hsqldb/hsqldb";
final public static String  DRIVER  =  "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
final public static String  USERNAME  =  "sa";
final public static String  PASSWORD  =  "";
final public static String  SCHEMA_NAME  =  "PUBLIC";

public static JdbcDatabaseTester createHsqldbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return new JdbcDatabaseTester(DRIVER, URL,  USERNAME, PASSWORD, SCHEMA_NAME);
}
```

thanks for anyone who knows how to solve this warning. 
BTW I have saw many questions about this issue but had not found any good answer

Comment: Consider adding links to the questions you found already, it can help others help you.

Comment: It seems dbuit is reading the column label, then attempts to use this temporary label to access the real column name in the database metadata.

Comment: you are right! he is using the column name instead of column label. I didn't find any workaround for this bug.

Comment: Please create a bug report with a patch or code snippets to fix https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/bugs/ or a merge request with the fix https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/code.git/ci/master/tree/

Comment: I have opened a bug report.
https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/bugs/393/

Answer (score 0):

Different JDBC drivers return the underlying column name or the column alias in their ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(int) calls

HSQLDB returns the underlying column name for the getColumnName(int) call. You can get HSQLDB to return the column alias (if any) with the connection property `;get_column_name=false` appended to the connection URL. See the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_props